# Atmel SAMD21 DMA Abort issue

Tags: c, arm, atmel, dma, cortex-m

Due to some design requirement, I need to change DMA descriptor at runtime. To achieve this, I am following below steps:

1. Abort DMA channel. DMA hardware will then save currently executing descriptor at 
   write_back RAM location of same DMA channel.
2. Wait until Abort Completed
3. Modify DMA descriptor on write_back RAM location.
4. Enable DMA channel again

This is code snippet I am using:

```
//Select DMA channel
DMAC->CHID.reg = DMAC_CHID_ID(cSPIDMAResource0.channel_id);

//Abort Selected DMA channel
DMAC->CHCTRLA.reg &= ~DMA_CHANNEL_ENABLE_BIT_POS;

//Wait until Abort completed
while((DMAC->CHCTRLA.reg & DMA_CHANNEL_ENABLE_BIT_POS) == DMA_CHANNEL_ENABLE_BIT_POS);

/*
    Modify Descriptor here 
*/

//Enable DMA channel
DMAC->CHCTRLA.reg |= DMA_CHANNEL_ENABLE_BIT_POS;
```

Above mentioned steps work fine without any problem, But I am facing Descriptor corruption issue during long run.

DMA hardware is storing currently executing descriptor at the write_back RAM location of another DMA channel (instead of own write_back RAM location) when DMA abort is performed.

If anyone has any idea of what went wrong, or has an idea of how I can avoid the Descriptor corruption issue completely, I would like to try it out.

Comment: Possibly the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62833342/atmel-samd21-dmac-writeback-failure

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the atmel software framework's dma driver?  Here's how they do the abort.

```
void dma_abort_job(struct dma_resource *resource)
{
    uint32_t write_size;
    uint32_t total_size;

    Assert(resource);
    Assert(resource->channel_id != DMA_INVALID_CHANNEL);

    system_interrupt_enter_critical_section();

    DMAC->CHID.reg = DMAC_CHID_ID(resource->channel_id);
    DMAC->CHCTRLA.reg = 0;

    system_interrupt_leave_critical_section();

    /* Get transferred size */
    total_size = descriptor_section[resource->channel_id].BTCNT.reg;
    write_size = _write_back_section[resource->channel_id].BTCNT.reg;
    resource->transfered_size = total_size - write_size;

    resource->job_status = STATUS_ABORTED;
}
```

One difference that could explain the problem is the disabling of interrupts via `system_interrupt_leave_critical_section()` during the register write for aborting the dma channel.

Comment: I also tried disabling the interrupts during DMAC register access, but it did not resolve the issue

Comment: @GOKU Did you ever found the answer to this problem?